# Polars - Search results between two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

So I am using Polars DF and got a bit stuck in regards to a task I am trying to do.

So basically I have a df, lets call it auctiondf which can contain a lot of "auctions"
I also have a trackingdf which contains items/auctions I want to track with specific search criterias.

In the trackingdf there will always be filled out an ItemId (Mandatory), the rest of the fields are however not mandatory to have been filled out.

If only the ItemId in the trackingDF is filled out, then I want to find all the auctions/items from auctionDF with that ItemId regardless of the other "columns"

If however any of the other fields has been filled out, those criterias has to be met as well, such as Realmname, Stat[x] and buyoutgold

There can be 5 stats from stat0 to stat4, I dont care about the order, so if possible it would be nice that the "search" doesn't care about the order either.

lets say ItemId has to be 15331 and I have put in +3 Stamina in Stat0 and +3 Agility in Stat1, then it's fine it finds results in AuctionDF where the ItemId is 15331 and Stat0 being +3 Agility and Stat 1 being +3 Stamina as long as the Stat[x] criteria is met.

auctionDF['Buyout'] of course cant exceed the amount in the trackingdf['buyoutgold'] column, however if it's blank the auctionDF['Buyout'] can be any amount

I hope the above makes sense and if you got any questions, please feel free to ask :)

```
import polars as pl

auctiondata = {"ItemId": [15331, 15332, 15333, 15213, 15331, 15213],
               "AuctionId": [2084868458, 2085008809, 2087827052, 2087835700, 2087827999, 2087827997],
               "RealmName": ['Gehennas', 'Gehennas', 'Mograine', 'Lakeshire', 'Gehennas', 'Bloodfang'],
               "Stat0": ['+3 Stamina', '+2 Intelelct', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina'],
               "Stat1": ['+3 Agility', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Intellect', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility', '+3 Agility'],
               "Stat2": ['', '', '', '','',''],
               "Stat3": ['', '', '', '','',''],
               "Stat4": ['', '', '', '','',''],
               "buyoutgold": ['40', '', '', '', '120','']}

trackingdata = {"ItemId": [15331, 15213, 15333],
               "RealmName": ['Gehennas', '', 'Mograine'],
               "Stat0": ['+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina'],
               "Stat1": ['+3 Agility', '+3 Agility', '+3 Intellect'],
               "Stat2": ['', '', ''],
               "Stat3": ['', '', ''],
               "Stat4": ['', '', ''],
               "buyoutgold": ['50', '', '']}

resultdata = {"ItemId": [15331, 15333, 15213, 15213],
               "AuctionId": [2084868458, 2087827052, 2087835700, 2087827997],
               "RealmName": ['Gehennas', 'Mograine', 'Lakeshire', 'Bloodfang'],
               "Stat0": ['+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility', '+3 Stamina'],
               "Stat1": ['+3 Agility', '+3 Intellect', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility'],
               "Stat2": ['', '', '', ''],
               "Stat3": ['', '', '', ''],
               "Stat4": ['', '', '', ''],
               "buyoutgold": ['40', '', '', '']}

auctiondf = pl.DataFrame(auctiondata)
print(auctiondf)

trackingdf = pl.DataFrame(trackingdata)
print(trackingdf)

resultdf = pl.DataFrame(resultdata)
print(resultdf)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's expand your Auction DataFrame by two lines so that we can clarify something.

```py
import polars as pl

auctiondata = {"ItemId": [15331, 15332, 15333, 15213, 15331, 15213] + [15213, 15213],
               "AuctionId": [2084868458, 2085008809, 2087827052, 2087835700, 2087827999,
                             2087827997] + [-1, -2],
               "RealmName": ['Gehennas', 'Gehennas', 'Mograine', 'Lakeshire', 'Gehennas',
                             'Bloodfang'] + ['Euripides', 'Euripides'],
               "Stat0": ['+3 Stamina', '+2 Intelelct', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility', '+3 Stamina',
                         '+3 Stamina'] + ['+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina'],
               "Stat1": ['+3 Agility', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Intellect', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility',
                         '+3 Agility'] + ['+3 Agility', ''],
               "Stat2": ['', '', '', '','',''] + ['+10 Strength', ''],
               "Stat3": [''] * 8,
               "Stat4": [''] * 8,
               "buyoutgold": ['40', '', '', '', '120',''] + ['', '']}
trackingdata = {"ItemId": [15331, 15213, 15333],
               "RealmName": ['Gehennas', '', 'Mograine'],
               "Stat0": ['+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina'],
               "Stat1": ['+3 Agility', '+3 Agility', '+3 Intellect'],
               "Stat2": ['', '', ''],
               "Stat3": ['', '', ''],
               "Stat4": ['', '', ''],
               "buyoutgold": ['50', '', '']}
resultdata = {"ItemId": [15331, 15333, 15213, 15213],
               "AuctionId": [2084868458, 2087827052, 2087835700, 2087827997],
               "RealmName": ['Gehennas', 'Mograine', 'Lakeshire', 'Bloodfang'],
               "Stat0": ['+3 Stamina', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility', '+3 Stamina'],
               "Stat1": ['+3 Agility', '+3 Intellect', '+3 Stamina', '+3 Agility'],
               "Stat2": ['', '', '', ''],
               "Stat3": ['', '', '', ''],
               "Stat4": ['', '', '', ''],
               "buyoutgold": ['40', '', '', '']}

auctiondf = pl.DataFrame(auctiondata)
trackingdf = pl.DataFrame(trackingdata)
resultdf = pl.DataFrame(resultdata)
print(auctiondf)
```

```
shape: (8, 9)
┌────────┬────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ AuctionId  ┆ RealmName ┆ Stat0        ┆ Stat1        ┆ Stat2        ┆ Stat3 ┆ Stat4 ┆ buyoutgold │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ i64        ┆ str       ┆ str          ┆ str          ┆ str          ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ str        │
╞════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 15331  ┆ 2084868458 ┆ Gehennas  ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ 40         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15332  ┆ 2085008809 ┆ Gehennas  ┆ +2 Intelelct ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15333  ┆ 2087827052 ┆ Mograine  ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆ +3 Intellect ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ 2087835700 ┆ Lakeshire ┆ +3 Agility   ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15331  ┆ 2087827999 ┆ Gehennas  ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ 120        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ 2087827997 ┆ Bloodfang ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ -1         ┆ Euripides ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆ +3 Agility   ┆ +10 Strength ┆       ┆       ┆            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ -2         ┆ Euripides ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆              ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆            │
└────────┴────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Here's the algorithm:

```py
result = (
    auctiondf
    .join(
        trackingdf,
        on="ItemId",
        suffix="_tracking",
    )
    .filter((pl.col('RealmName_tracking') == "") | (pl.col('RealmName') == pl.col('RealmName_tracking')))
    .with_columns(pl.col('^buyoutgold.*$').cast(pl.Float64, strict=False).keep_name())
    .filter((pl.col('buyoutgold_tracking').is_null()) | (pl.col('buyoutgold') <= pl.col('buyoutgold_tracking')))
    .with_columns(
        auction_stats=pl.concat_list(pl.col(r'^Stat.*\d$')).list.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element() != '')),
        tracking_stats=pl.concat_list(pl.col(r'^Stat.*_tracking$')).list.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element() != '')),
    )
    .filter(pl.col('tracking_stats').list.difference(pl.col('auction_stats')).list.lengths()==0)
    .select(pl.exclude(r'^.*_tracking$'))
    .select(pl.exclude(r'^.*_stats$'))
)
with pl.Config(set_tbl_cols=10):
    print(result)
```

```
shape: (5, 9)
┌────────┬────────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ AuctionId  ┆ RealmName ┆ Stat0      ┆ Stat1        ┆ Stat2        ┆ Stat3 ┆ Stat4 ┆ buyoutgold │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ i64        ┆ str       ┆ str        ┆ str          ┆ str          ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ f64        │
╞════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 15331  ┆ 2084868458 ┆ Gehennas  ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ 40.0       │
│ 15333  ┆ 2087827052 ┆ Mograine  ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Intellect ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ null       │
│ 15213  ┆ 2087835700 ┆ Lakeshire ┆ +3 Agility ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ null       │
│ 15213  ┆ 2087827997 ┆ Bloodfang ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ null       │
│ 15213  ┆ -1         ┆ Euripides ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Agility   ┆ +10 Strength ┆       ┆       ┆ null       │
└────────┴────────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

##### Some notes

Let's take a look at the results just before we exclude the Tracking DF columns:

```
shape: (5, 16)
┌────────┬────────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ AuctionId  ┆ RealmName ┆ Stat0      ┆ Stat1        ┆ Stat2        ┆ Stat3 ┆ Stat4 ┆ buyoutgold ┆ RealmName_tracking ┆ Stat0_tracking ┆ Stat1_tracking ┆ Stat2_tracking ┆ Stat3_tracking ┆ Stat4_tracking ┆ buyoutgold_tracking │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---                ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---                 │
│ i64    ┆ i64        ┆ str       ┆ str        ┆ str          ┆ str          ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ f64        ┆ str                ┆ str            ┆ str            ┆ str            ┆ str            ┆ str            ┆ f64                 │
╞════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 15331  ┆ 2084868458 ┆ Gehennas  ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ 40.0       ┆ Gehennas           ┆ +3 Stamina     ┆ +3 Agility     ┆                ┆                ┆                ┆ 50.0                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15333  ┆ 2087827052 ┆ Mograine  ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Intellect ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ null       ┆ Mograine           ┆ +3 Stamina     ┆ +3 Intellect   ┆                ┆                ┆                ┆ null                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ 2087835700 ┆ Lakeshire ┆ +3 Agility ┆ +3 Stamina   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ null       ┆                    ┆ +3 Stamina     ┆ +3 Agility     ┆                ┆                ┆                ┆ null                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ 2087827997 ┆ Bloodfang ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Agility   ┆              ┆       ┆       ┆ null       ┆                    ┆ +3 Stamina     ┆ +3 Agility     ┆                ┆                ┆                ┆ null                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15213  ┆ -1         ┆ Euripides ┆ +3 Stamina ┆ +3 Agility   ┆ +10 Strength ┆       ┆       ┆ null       ┆                    ┆ +3 Stamina     ┆ +3 Agility     ┆                ┆                ┆                ┆ null                │
└────────┴────────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Notice that the last line contains `+10 Strength`.  I wasn't sure what to do with auction id's that contain Stats that are not in the tracking DF.  In this case, the Auction ID contained all the stats contained in the Tracking ID, plus one that wasn't in the Tracking ID: `+10 Strength`.  If that's not what you want, we can change the algorithm easily.

We cast both `buyoutgold` columns to numbers so that we can make the comparison.

##### The Stats columns

For the Stats columns, we're mimicking set difference.  Basically, we're asking "Is there any Stat in the Tracking DF that is not in the Auction DF?".

To accomplish this, we use [`.list.difference`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.difference.html)